# Can't import: 'unable to import rest_framework' when importing serializer? (windows)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 'rest_framework' in my INSTALLED_APPS of settings.py and I can import it with no problem in cmd﻿

[image]

But I receive an "Unable to import 'rest_framework'" message

[image]

I can import rest_framework no problem in my cmd prompt, so I really have no idea what the issue is?

Comment: in the editor settings you may not choosing the right python console version if more than a python installed in your system

Answer (score 9):

[vs code_taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTOAu.png)
I see you're using VS Code. A quick fix is to go to the Python environment settings at the bottom-left corner[Taskbar] of the VS Code-> tap on [Python 2/3...] and it will prompt you to choose the environment from the default Python installation directory to your Project Virtual Environment(venv) directory and that should fix all the import issues.

Comment: Thanks!worked for me