# django.urls, django rest and django-cors-headers - trouble with imports

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-cors-headers

(Note: the issue with the django-cors-headers was solved - I was just missing one comma in the INSTALLED_APPS inside the settings.py file)

When I activate my virtual environment and when I write this command -

```
pip list
```

the result is -

```
asgiref             3.3.1
Django              3.1.6
django-cors-headers 3.7.0
djangorestframework 3.12.2
pip                 21.0.1
pytz                2021.1
setuptools          52.0.0
sqlparse            0.4.1
wheel               0.36.2
```

But I am still getting the errors, which are listed below -

in the urls.py files -

```
No name 'path' in module 'django.urls'
No name 'include' in module 'django.urls'
```

in the views.py file -

```
Unable to import 'rest_framework.decorators'
Unable to import 'rest_framework.response'
```

Full code of the files, where the errors come from, can be found in this post -
[A large number of problems with React, Django, Django REST and Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239527/a-large-number-of-problems-with-react-django-django-rest-and-axios)

---

(the following issue (regarding to the django-cors-headers) was solved)

---

When I try to run -

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I am getting the following error -

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corsheadersbase'
```

But I have installed django-cors-headers and I have implemented it to the settings.py
as it is suggested here -
https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

relevant parts of the settings.py code -

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...    
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
     ...
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

Solving these little errors would really help me a lot. Could anybody give me some hint, please?
Thank You very much in advance.

Comment: Only reason I can see is that `manage.py` that you are running is picking up `wrong python executable`, check python versions installed and run `manage.py` using correct one, may be it is `python3 manage.py XXX` with respective to your application or check the shebang in `manage.py` file

Comment: my global python version is 3.8.5 and it is the same as the version in the virtual environment. how would the command for running this specific version look like? i am sorry, but i am not sure, what the shebang is.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python3` in manage.py and I believe you are running manage.py commands only after activating virtualenv

Comment: i see. that is the very first line the manage.py file. you are correct. i am always using virtual environment, when it comes to django.

Comment: have you also tested imports by opening python shell in virtual environment ?

Comment: when i try to open shell in the command prompt, (when i write - python)  i am getting this error - Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

(this is probably some collision with the anaconda environment. this is the first time i see this)

Comment: i am sometimes using anaconda in order to access the jupyter notebook, but most of the time i am working in vscode or atom.

Comment: If you are not using conda then `conda deactivate` then activate virtualenv/ or create a new one using `pyenv or virtualenv or conda(create new)` or utitility you are familiar to use virtualenvs  and install libraries and try again.

Comment: Please check the python path using the following commands first

asif@ck ~> which python
/home/asif/.pyenv/shims/python
asif@ck ~> which python3
/home/asif/.pyenv/shims/python3

Answer (score 0):

You must add these libraries to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    ...
]
```

Comment: I did that - I was referencing to the settings.py file as being taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your python interpreter has been selected in your IDE. Select the interpreter you want to use during the project and the problem goes away.