# Products on the homepage are not being displayed properly (Django, Django Rest and React)

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, render

this problem has already been solved. (the link number 1 contains the solution) this post is the second part of the following series -

1. [A large number of problems with React, Django, Django REST and Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239527/a-large-number-of-problems-with-react-django-django-rest-and-axios)
2. [Products on the homepage are not being displayed properly (Django, Django Rest and React)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66422454/products-on-the-homepage-are-not-being-displayed-properly-django-django-rest-a)
3. [(React and Django) Displaying products on the homepage is working fine, but when I click on any particular product, then the rendering is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66588419/react-and-django-displaying-products-on-the-homepage-is-working-fine-but-when)

I am using Django, Django Rest and React. My products are being displayed like this -

[image]

But I should see them like this -

[image]

ProductScreen.js -

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Button, Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import Rating from "../components/Rating";
import products from "../products";

function ProductScreen({ match }) {
  const product = products.find((p) => p._id == match.params.id);
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/" className="btn btn-light my-3">
        Go Back
      </Link>
      <Row>
        <Col md={6}>
          <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
        </Col>

        <Col md={3}>
          <ListGroup variant="flush">
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h3>{product.name}</h3>
            </ListGroup.Item>

            <ListGroup.Item>
              <Rating
                value={product.rating}
                text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}
                color={"#f8e825"}
              />
            </ListGroup.Item>

            <ListGroup.Item>Price: ${product.price}</ListGroup.Item>

            <ListGroup.Item>Description: {product.description}</ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
        </Col>

        <Col md={3}>
          <Card>
            <ListGroup variant="flush">
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Price:</Col>
                  <Col>
                    <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Status:</Col>
                  <Col>
                    {product.countInStock > 0 ? "In Stock" : "Out of Stock"}
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Button
                  className="btn-block"
                  disabled={product.countInStock == 0}
                  type="button"
                >
                  Add to Cart
                </Button>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

HomeScreen.js -

```
import React, { useState, useEffect }  from "react";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Product from "../components/Product";
import axios from "axios"

function HomeScreen() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    
    async function fetchProducts() {
     const { data } = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/')
     setProducts(data)
    }  

    fetchProducts()
  },[] )

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Latest Products</h1>
      <Row>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
            <Product product={product} />
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

views.py -

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .products import products

# Create your views here.
@api_view(['GET'])
def getRoutes(request):
    routes = [
    '/api/products/',
    '/api/products/create/',

    'api/products/upload/',

    'api/products/<id>/reviews/',

    'api/products/top/',
    'api/products/<id>/',

    'api/products/delete/<id>/',
    'api/products/<update>/<id>/',

    ]
    return Response(routes)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getProducts(request):
    return Response(products)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getProduct(request, pk):
    product = None
    for i in products:
        if i['_id'] == pk:
            product = i
            break

    return Response(product)
```

Could anybody give me some hint please? Thank You very much in advance.

Comment: It's very hard to see what's go wrong? please post your project on github to reproduce, at least open browser console and check for warnings, errors...

Comment: Here is the github page of the finished project - https://github.com/divanov11/proshop_django

Is it safe to post my whole project on github, if f.e. the settings.py contains some sort of a secret key?

Comment: I am still a beginner when it comes to programming, so please be patient with me and my questions.

Comment: index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. (this is one of the errors from the console, that i am concerned about, i think that the other errors are harmless, because they were there even before, when things were fine)

Comment: The error has a more information inside of it - I will post it in the following 2 comments.

Comment: Check the render method of `HomeScreen`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at Col (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:11723:23)
    at HomeScreen (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1547:89)

Comment: at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:50716:29)
    at div
    at Container (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:11920:23)
    at main
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:50351:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:49971:35)
    at App
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
localhost

Comment: Hi, you should seperate dev and production environment, and open network tab to see anything abnormal