# (React and Django) Displaying products on the homepage is working fine, but when I click on any particular product, then the rendering is wrong

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-views, rendering

this post is the third part of the following series - (You can skip these first two parts, however - it can serve as a reference)

1. [A large number of problems with React, Django, Django REST and Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239527/a-large-number-of-problems-with-react-django-django-rest-and-axios)
2. [Products on the homepage are not being displayed properly (Django, Django Rest and React)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66422454/products-on-the-homepage-are-not-being-displayed-properly-django-django-rest-a)
3. [(React and Django) Displaying products on the homepage is working fine, but when I click on any particular product, then the rendering is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66588419/react-and-django-displaying-products-on-the-homepage-is-working-fine-but-when)

(Note: The code of HomeScreen.Js and ProductScreen.js is updated in this third part, so it is different from the codes of these files, which are being shown in the first two parts)

My homepage looks like this -
[image]

But when I click on any particular product, I get this result -
[image]

I was consulting this issue with my friend, who has told me, that my React code should be fine and the problem should be somewhere inside the Django.

When I am checking my command prompt (from which I am running my Django server) - I am getting this output, when trying to display the product number 1 -
[11/Mar/2021 19:18:05] "GET /api/products/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2123

Please take a look at the code and maybe You will be able to find some hidden bug.

HomeScreen.js -

```
import React, { useState, useEffect }  from "react";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Product from "../components/Product";
import axios from "axios"

function HomeScreen() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    
    async function fetchProducts() {
     const { data } = await axios.get('/api/products/')
     setProducts(data)
    }  

    fetchProducts()
  },[] )

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Latest Products</h1>
      <Row>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
            <Product product={product} />
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

ProductScreen.js -

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Button, Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import Rating from "../components/Rating";
import axios from "axios"

function ProductScreen({ match }) {

  const [product, setProduct] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    
    async function fetchProduct() {
     const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${match.params.id}`)
     setProduct(data)
    }  

    fetchProduct()
  },[] )

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/" className="btn btn-light my-3">
        Go Back
      </Link>
      <Row>
        <Col md={6}>
          <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
        </Col>

        <Col md={3}>
          <ListGroup variant="flush">
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h3>{product.name}</h3>
            </ListGroup.Item>

            <ListGroup.Item>
              <Rating
                value={product.rating}
                text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}
                color={"#f8e825"}
              />
            </ListGroup.Item>

            <ListGroup.Item>Price: ${product.price}</ListGroup.Item>

            <ListGroup.Item>Description: {product.description}</ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
        </Col>

        <Col md={3}>
          <Card>
            <ListGroup variant="flush">
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Price:</Col>
                  <Col>
                    <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Status:</Col>
                  <Col>
                    {product.countInStock > 0 ? "In Stock" : "Out of Stock"}
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Button
                  className="btn-block"
                  disabled={product.countInStock == 0}
                  type="button"
                >
                  Add to Cart
                </Button>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

package.json -

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.7.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

urls.py (inside the base app folder) -

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    
    url('products/', views.getProducts, name="products"),
    url('products/<str:pk>/', views.getProduct, name="product"),
    url('routes/', views.getRoutes, name="routes"),
]
```

views.py -

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .products import products

# Create your views here.
@api_view(['GET'])
def getRoutes(request):
    routes = [
    '/api/products/',
    '/api/products/create/',

    'api/products/upload/',

    'api/products/<id>/reviews/',

    'api/products/top/',
    'api/products/<id>/',

    'api/products/delete/<id>/',
    'api/products/<update>/<id>/',

    ]
    return Response(routes)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getProducts(request):
    return Response(products)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getProduct(request, pk):
    product = None
    for i in products:
        if i['_id'] == pk:
            product = i
            break

    return Response(product)
```

Please let me know, if You see any solution to this bug. Thank You very much for Your eventual answer.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by changing Django´s version from 3.1.6 to 3.1.4 and I have also changed this -

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    
    url('products/', views.getProducts, name="products"),
    url('products/<str:pk>/', views.getProduct, name="product"),
    url('routes/', views.getRoutes, name="routes"),
]
```

back to this -

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    
    path('products/', views.getProducts, name="products"),
    path('products/<str:pk>/', views.getProduct, name="product"),
    path('routes/', views.getRoutes, name="routes"),
]
```